# Weird output from ls command in Terminal

Tags: terminal, command-line

I recently started customising my Mac terminal and adding Vim stuff. After some time I noticed that when executing `ls` command, I keep getting:

`)<CR>?vnoremap <Space> zf??`

along-with regular `ls` command output. For example:

```
$ ls
)<CR>?vnoremap <Space> zf?? Documents                   Movies                      Public
Applications                Downloads                   Music                       Workspace
Desktop                     Library                     Pictures
```

I have no idea where it is coming from. It happens only in `ls` command and it happens in both built-in Terminal.app and iTerm2 (zsh shell).

I have tried grep-ing `<Space>` pattern (etc.) in my Home directory, but there is no file with such string.

Comment: It means you have a file with that name in that directory. The `?` is a placeholder for some control character. What do you see with `ls -lF *noremap*`

Comment: oh wow, indeed that was a file lol

Answer (score 1):

`noremap` - command from vim, so when saving file, the name has been assigned. A detailed `ls` would help or installing something like Midnight Commander, which runs with as simple `mc` command and helps to evaluate it visually.

Answer (score -1):

Here are the terminal commands for working with the file.  the backslash \ is a way to escape special characters.  The tab key will expand the filename.

so you type 
ls \(
then you press the tab key.  the ls the l is a lower case L

the rm is the remove command.  You need to be careful when using this command.  the files deleted are gone forever!

I'll put a space between the r and m, but you need to remove the space. The -i says to verify the delete. be certain not to have any other funny characters in the rm line. you cannot see it, but I typed ls (  then pressed the tab key.

```
mac $ touch \(abc
mac $ ls
(abc          duplicateOne  one           subdirD.app/  three         two
mac $ ls \(abc 
(abc
mac $ r m -i \(abc 
remove (abc? y
mac $
```